# Unable to ping KVM/Qemu VM: Administratively prohibited

Tags: networking, qemu, kvm

I am trying to setup routing to a KVM on my computer. When I try to ping a VM from another machine, I get the error message "Administratively prohibited". The VM can send IPv6 traffic out (egress) but in (ingress) is not working.

I cleared my firewall rules with `iptables -F` and `sudo ufw status` is `inactive`.

My configuration is as follows:

In the graphical Virtual Machine Manager, I created a network called "network-ipv6" and gave it the range `2600:3a30:c450:a410::/64`. It assigned the host machine with the IP address `2600:3a30:c450:a410::1` on `virbr1` and the VM received `2600:3a30:c450:a410::2`.

I can ping between the host/hypervisor and into the VM. Great.

I also setup routing between `2600:3a30:c450:a400::/64` and `2600:3a30:c450:a410::/64` through the host/hypervisor.

But when I try to ping from another machine on a different subnet (`2600:3a30:c450:**a400**:ba27:ebff:fecf:38ba`) the sender receives the following:

```
From 2600:4030:2450:a400:c1c1:463c:d0e9:3dbe icmp_seq=59 Destination unreachable: Administratively prohibited
```

In this case, `:3dbe` is the Host/hypervisor, while `38ba` is the sender.

The packet arrives at the host's wifi interface, I verify via `tcpdump -i wlp170s0` that an ICMPv6 echo request lands there.

```
18:47:05.648414 IP6 2600:3a30:c450:a400:ba27:ebff:fecf:38ba > 2600:3a30:c450:a410::2: ICMP6, echo request, id 15, seq 1, length 64
18:47:05.648472 IP6 2600:3a30:c450:a400:c1c1:463c:d0e9:3dbe > 2600:3a30:c450:a400:ba27:ebff:fecf:38ba: ICMP6, destination unreachable,  unreachable prohibited 2600:3a30:c450:a410::2, length 112
```

Notice: `unreachable prohibited`. why?

The routing is as follows:

```
$ ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2600:3a30:c450:a400::/64 dev wlp170s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
2600:3a30:c450:a410:::/64 dev virbr1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
...
```

I also see that `virbr1`'s sysctl is set to forwarding.

```
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.virbr1.forwarding
net.ipv6.conf.virbr1.forwarding = 1
```

```
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.wlp170s0.forwarding
net.ipv6.conf.wlp170s0.forwarding = 1
```

If relevant, my host/hypervisor is running Pop_OS, which is Ubuntu-based.

Why the error `Administratively prohibited`?